# Detect with JavaScript or jQuery if CSS transform 2D is available

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms

I'm displaying a element on my site which I rotate with -90deg
but if a browser doesn't support the CSS transform the element
looks misspositioned and not really good.
Now I want to detect with JavaScript or jQuery (it's indifferent
if jQ or JS because I use/loaded already jQ on my site) if this rotation via CSS is supported?

I know [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) but just for that little thing I don't want to include that whole library (and speed down the website speed load).

Comment: Have a look at source of [jQuery transform plugin](https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transform.js/) (which extends jQuery `.css()` and `.animate()` functions) how they did it. Or, better, just use that plugin :) It's small.

Comment: You don't have to download the whole bundle from modernizr, you could just select 2d transform from the custom download

Comment: I just looked at how modernizr does things and borrowed small pieces from it for a project of mine.

Comment: @BalusC Post this as answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 32):

Here's a function based on Liam's answer. It will return either the name of the first supported prefix or `false` if none of the prefixes are supported.

```
function getSupportedTransform() {
    var prefixes = 'transform WebkitTransform MozTransform OTransform msTransform'.split(' ');
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    for(var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++) {
        if(div && div.style[prefixes[i]] !== undefined) {
            return prefixes[i];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Nice, up-voted. Just to suggest to have 'div' element created outside for loop.

Answer (score 4):

This is about as simple as you get and a [jsfiddle](http://jsbin.com/uweyij).  It no longer goes on an infinite loop.

```
function getSupportedTransform() {
    var prefixes = 'transform WebkitTransform MozTransform OTransform msTransform'.split(' ');
    for(var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++) {
        if(document.createElement('div').style[prefixes[i]] !== undefined) {
            return prefixes[i];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This goes on in an infinite loop if the browser doesn't support transforms (will also eat all the ram).

Comment: What's the purpose of 'el' variable? I guess you wanted not to create div element in every pass, but you didn't use it. And obviously, infinite loop in case no prefix is available.

Comment: @Dan It doesn't go on an infinite loop anymore.

Comment: @Sinisa I changed the code so it does't go into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code I'm using to detect if CSS3 transitions are supported:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('style', 'transition:top 1s ease;-webkit-transition:top 1s ease;-moz-transition:top 1s ease;-o-transition:top 1s ease;');
document.body.appendChild(div);
var cssTransitionsSupported = !!(div.style.transition || div.style.webkitTransition || div.style.MozTransition || div.style.OTransitionDuration);

div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
div = null;
```

I'm purposefully not looking for Microsoft support since Microsoft hasn't yet shipped a browser that supports CSS3 transitions and I don't want my code automatically supporting an implementation I haven't tested yet in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Just pull what you need out of Modernizr

First we need the testProps function

```
   /**
     * testProps is a generic CSS / DOM property test; if a browser supports
     *   a certain property, it won't return undefined for it.
     *   A supported CSS property returns empty string when its not yet set.
     */
    function testProps( props, prefixed ) {
        for ( var i in props ) {
            if ( mStyle[ props[i] ] !== undefined ) {
                return prefixed == 'pfx' ? props[i] : true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Then run the cssTransform test

```
var tests = [];
 tests['csstransforms'] = function() {
        return !!testProps(['transformProperty', 'WebkitTransform', 'MozTransform', 'OTransform', 'msTransform']);
    };
```

if tests['csstransforms'] is true, then you have the feature available.

Comment: There seems to be a mistake in the code: `mStyle is not defined`

Comment: Define it then :) var myStyle = []

Comment: I don't think you can just define it... looks lime mStyle is a global that has the browser supported css props in there....this function is completely useless if you have to define that variable as it will always be false...

Answer (score 0):

This code tests for **2D transforms** support.

It can be easily adjusted to detect **3D transforms** support instead. Just add 'translateZ(1)' to test CSS (see `defaultTestValues` in source code).

The plus of this code is that it detects the vendor prefix supported (if any). Call it:

```
testCSSSupport('transform')
```

Possible return values:

`false`,   when feature unsupported, or

```
{
    vendor: 'moz',
    cssStyle: '-moz-transform',
    jsStyle: 'MozTransform'
}
```

when feature supported

```
/**
 * Test for CSS3 feature support. Single-word properties only by now.
 * This function is not generic, but it works well for transition and transform at least
 */
testCSSSupport: function (feature, cssTestValue/* optional */) {
    var testDiv,
        featureCapital = feature.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + feature.substr(1),
        vendors = ['', 'webkit', 'moz', 'ms'],
        jsPrefixes = ['', 'Webkit', 'Moz', 'ms'],
        defaultTestValues = {
            transform: 'translateX(.5em)'
           // This will test for 2D transform support
           // Add translateZ(1) to test 3D transform
        },
        testFunctions = {
            transform: function (jsProperty, computed) {
                return computed[jsProperty].substr(0, 9) === 'matrix3d(';
            }
        };

    function isStyleSupported(feature, jsPrefixedProperty) {
        if (jsPrefixedProperty in testDiv.style) {
            var testVal = cssTestValue || defaultTestValues[feature],
                testFn = testFunctions[feature];
            if (!testVal) {
                return false;
            }

            //Assume browser without getComputedStyle is either IE8 or something even more poor
            if (!window.getComputedStyle) {
                return false;
            }

            testDiv.style[jsPrefixedProperty] = testVal;
            var computed = window.getComputedStyle(testDiv);

            if (testFn) {
                return testFn(jsPrefixedProperty, computed);
            }
            else {
                return computed[jsPrefixedProperty] === testVal;
            }
        }
    }

    var cssPrefixedProperty,
        jsPrefixedProperty,
        testDiv = document.createElement('div');

    for (var i = 0; i < vendors.length; i++) {
        if (i === 0) {
            cssPrefixedProperty = feature;  //todo: this code now works for single-word features only!
            jsPrefixedProperty = feature;   //therefore box-sizing -> boxSizing won't work here
        }
        else {
            cssPrefixedProperty = '-' + vendors[i] + '-' + feature;
            jsPrefixedProperty = jsPrefixes[i] + featureCapital;
        }

        if (isStyleSupported(feature, jsPrefixedProperty)) {
            return {
                vendor: vendors[i],
                cssStyle: cssPrefixedProperty,
                jsStyle: jsPrefixedProperty
            };
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```