# JavaScript to dynamically select style transformations

Tags: javascript, css-transforms

Applying a rotation to an image element and would like to make this cross browser compliant.  This will be acted many times on several elements.

I know I can do this;

```
  elem.style.WebkitTransform = "rotate("+de+"deg)"; 
  elem.style.MozTransform = "rotate("+de+"deg)";
  elem.style.msTransform = "rotate("+des+"deg)";
  elem.style.OTransform = "rotate("+de+"deg)";
  elem.style.transform = "rotate("+de+"deg)";
```

This just seems messy and I did wonder what happens if a browser recognizes more than one of the transforms?

I could nest these with an if else sequence or switch using browser sniffing but I avoid sniffing if possible and the use of either method would make it even messier.  So I utilized code from here
[Detect Transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212102/detect-with-javascript-or-jquery-if-css-transform-2d-is-available)
This returns the name of the first recognised transform {transform WebkitTransform MozTransform OTransform msTransform} which I assign to the variable mytransform.

Then I wrote a set of functions

```
function activetransform(elem,de) {
  elem.style.transform = "rotate("+de+"deg)";
}
.
.
.
function activemsTransform(elem,de) {
  elem.style.msTransform = "rotate("+de+"deg)";
}
```

Only one of these functions is used for the specific browser.
It is called by the rotate function

```
function rotate(timing){
  // selects elem
  // calculates angle
  window[mytransform](elem,de);
```

So only one transform is called, I don't need to repeat browser detection, use if or switch but I need an array lookup and a second function call.

What would be great is if I could replace all the transformation with;

```
elem.style.mytransform = "rotate("+de+"deg)";
```

Where the variable mytransform = name of the browser specific transform.

Comment: Have you considered making a CSS rule(s) that apply the cross-browser transforms, and using JS to apply/remove the class as needed? It may be simpler than trying to do all of it using JS alone.

Comment: How nice it would be to live in a world with no prefixes. No worries as long as you apply the same value to each, all browsers will do the same and pick just one (and usually simply not apply the others, not even in JS). But I fear that, for now, there is not really a better way to apply it. Yes you could check, but it would probably require more code and function calls than simply assigning it a couple of times.

Comment: Unless you are targeting old browsers, you really do not need the vendor prefixes.

Comment: Thank you, I don't think I can make the CSS class work as the movement is dynamic, so I would need to supply a variable.  Regarding the other option of just leaving in all the transforms; as long as only one of them was acted that would be fine but I was considering a performance loss due to the browser processing the non-required transforms.

Comment: I'd be curious to know that as well; Typically the browser will only apply a style once per rule if it recognizes multiple prefixes. I'm not sure how it behaves if this is set dynamically